# How can I get Google Photos' grid view to show complete photos on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-photos

On my PC using a web browser, I have Google Photos' grid view configured to show all photos in their entirety at a uniform height. This means landscape photos are the same height as portrait ones in the grid, but are wider. Panoramas are wider still, but they have the same height as everything else.

I want to achieve the same thing in Google Photos' grid view on my iPhone, but I can't find a way to do it. Pinching and zooming the grid view seems to show three options:

- All photos same height, but all cropped to squares, regardless of actual aspect ratio.
- Most photos shown as squares of a given height, but some (seemingly randomly chosen) are much larger. Landscapes and panoramas are cropped to squares.
- Photos are shown in their entirety, but the heights vary. Only two photos are shown per row.

Is there a way to get GP on iPhone to show all photos in their entirety in grid view while also using a uniform height for each image?